# Why nodes of a binary tree have links only from parent to children?

Tags: data-structures, tree

Why nodes of a binary tree have links only from parent to children? I know tha there is threaded binary tree but those are harder to implement. A binary tree with two links will allow traversal in both directions iteratively without a stack or queue.

I do not know of any such design. If there is one please let me know.

Edit1: Let me conjure a problem for this. I want to do traversal without recursion and without using extra memory in form of stack or queue.

PS: I am afraid that I am going to get flake and downvotes for this stupid question.

Comment: The problems for which a tree structure is well suited do not require such two way traversals.  If you tell us what problem you actually have then maybe someone can make a suggestion.

Comment: No I am not trying to solve a problem. It was just a question which came to mind. The thing is if we present a tree this way then we can also use like a linked list.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen like introsort and timsort are hybrid sorting algorithm. Perhaps we can have a hybrid data structure.

Comment: What do you mean “with two links”? What would the two links be?

Comment: @Ryan In C the structure would look like following: struct node { Data d; struct node* lchild; struct node* rchild; struct node* parent; };

Comment: @Bugbugbuggerbuggered: Who said you couldn’t do that? Accessing the parent of a node in a binary tree is common, e.g. when inserting into a binary heap.

Comment: @Ryan I have not seen a link to parent anywhere I have seen code. But then again I have seen very little. The only way I know is threaded binary tree. I will look at binary heap codes again at various places if they have a link to parent. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bugbugbuggerbuggered: One common storage format for binary trees is as an array, where for a child at 1-based index `i` the index of the parent is `i / 2`, which might be part of why you haven’t seen that.

Comment: I do not agree to the array part. That is applicable for very small trees where O(n) or O(logn) both does not matter.

Comment: A threaded binary tree is not that much more difficult to implement. You just have to flags that say whether the right/left references are children, or in-order/post-order successors. Just a little extra processing at insertion and deletion time.

Answer (score 2):

Some binary trees do require children to keep up with their parent, or even their grandparent, e.g. Splay Trees. However this is only to balance or splay the tree. The reason we only traverse a tree from the parent to the children is because we are usually searching for a specific node, and as long as the binary tree is implemented such that all left children are less than the parent, and all right children are greater than the parent (or vice-versa), we only need links in one direction to find that node. We start the search at the root and then iterate down, and if the node is in the tree, we are guaranteed to find it. If we started at a leaf, there is no guarantee we would find the node we want by going back to the root. The reason we don't have links from the child to the parent is because it is unnecessary for searches. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you refer me to a place where a splay tree has been shown having two way links.

Comment: While I agree to the fact that trees main purpose is for searching but that limits its usefulness in a way what a linked list offers. I am trying for killing two birds with one stone.

Comment: Binary Trees are better for searches because they are faster. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your binary tree besides searches? Here's a splay tree reference: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/why-does-the-splay-tree-rotation-algorithm-take-into-account-both-the-parent-and

Comment: but the link is not affirmative about 2 way links. I am not trying to accomplish anything. I want to use my binary tree as linked list without changing the storage structure.

Answer (score 0):

It can be, however, we should consider the balance between the memory usage and the complexity.

Yeah you can traverse the binary tree with an extra link in each node, but actually you are using the same extra memory as you do the traversal with a queue, which even run faster.

What binary search tree good at is that it can implement many searching problems in O(logN). It's fast enough and memory saving.

Answer (score 0):

> *Let me conjure a problem for this. I want to do traversal without recursion and without using extra memory in form of stack or queue.*

Have you considered that the parent pointers in the tree occupy space themselves?

They add O(N) memory to the tree to store parent pointer in order not to use O(log N) space during recursion.

What parent pointers allow us to do is to support an API whereby the caller can pass a pointer to a node and request an operation on it like "find the next node in order" (for example).

In this situation, we do not have a stack which holds the path to the root; we just receive a node "out of the blue" from the caller. With parent pointers, given a tree node, we can find its successor in amortized constant time O(1).

Implementations which don't require this functionality can save space by not including the parent pointers in the tree, and using recursion or an explicit stack structure for the root to leaf traversals.

Comment: Yes, I have. Say node holds a structure which is 1KB and pointer is 8 bytes then it is cheaper.

Comment: The relative size of the node data and the pointers doesn't affect O(N) memory overhead (stored parent pointers) versus O(log N) (backtracking space during root-to-leaf traversal).  Large data just makes the issue less significant.  Adding a parent pointer to a million-node tree means 8 million bytes: 8 megs.   A balanced tree of a million nodes needs a depth of about 20 for traversal: a tiny amount of overhead for the parent pointers in the stack. You save 8 megabytes by not storing the parent pointers in the tree. If it's 8 megabytes out of 8 gigabytes, you might not care.